# Excel data reading from Stream and save to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net MVC application, There is an option to upload data from an excel file. For that, I have used this on my controller.

```
public ActionResult ImportEmpDetails(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (excelFile.ContentLength == 0 || excelFile == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "Please select the excel file";
                    return View("EmpDetails");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
                    {
                        string path = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/" + excelFile.FileName);
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                        excelFile.SaveAs(path);
                        ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/") + path;
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

                        List<EmpDetailsVM> xcel = new List<EmpDetailsVM>();

                        for (int i = 2; i <= range.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {

                                EmpDetails emp = new EmpDetails();
                                int EmpNo = int.Parse(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 1]).Text);
                                var EmpId = (from c in db.CreateEmployee where c.EmpNo == EmpNo select c.Id).First();
                                emp.EmpID = EmpId;
                                emp.YearOfService = decimal.Parse(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 2]).Text);
                                emp.BasicSalary = decimal.Parse(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 3]).Text);
                                emp.EmpCatagory = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 4]).Text;
                                emp.EmpGrade = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 5]).Text;
                                int SupervisorId = int.Parse(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)range.Cells[i, 6]).Text);
                                var SupId = (from h in db.CreateEmployee where h.EmpNo == SupervisorId select h.Id).First();
                                emp.SupervisorId = SupId;


                                EmpDetailsVM data = new EmpDetailsVM();
                                data.EmpID = emp.EmpID;
                                data.YearOfService = emp.YearOfService;
                                data.BasicSalary = emp.BasicSalary;
                                data.EmpCatagory = emp.EmpCatagory;
                                data.EmpGrade = emp.EmpGrade;
                                data.SupervisorId = emp.SupervisorId;
                                xcel.Add(data);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                                ViewBag.Error = "Error in " + i + " record";
                                return View("EmpDetails");
                            }

                        }
                        if (xcel != null)
                        {

                            try
                            {

                                foreach (var item in xcel)
                                {
                                    int empID = item.EmpID;
                                    decimal yearOfService = item.YearOfService;
                                    decimal basicSalary = item.BasicSalary;
                                    string catagory = item.EmpCatagory;
                                    string grade = item.EmpGrade;
                                    int supId = item.SupervisorId;

                                    var isEmployeeExists = (from e in dbs.EmpDetails where e.EmpID == empID select e.Id).ToList();
                                    int EmpCount = isEmployeeExists.Count();

                                    if (EmpCount == 0)
                                    {
                                        EmpDetails e = new EmpDetails();
                                        e.EmpID = empID;
                                        e.YearOfService = yearOfService;
                                        e.BasicSalary = basicSalary;
                                        e.EmpCatagory = catagory;
                                        e.EmpGrade = grade;
                                        e.SupervisorId = supId;
                                        dbs.EmpDetails.Add(e);
                                        dbs.SaveChanges();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        EmpDetails EmpDetails = dbs.EmpDetails.Where(x => x.EmpID == empID).First();
                                        EmpDetails.YearOfService = yearOfService;
                                        EmpDetails.BasicSalary = basicSalary;
                                        EmpDetails.EmpCatagory = catagory;
                                        EmpDetails.EmpGrade = grade;
                                        EmpDetails.SupervisorId = supId;
                                        db.SaveChanges();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                                ViewBag.Error = "Error " + ex;
                            }

                            TempData["msg"] = "success";
                            return View("EmpDetails", xcel);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }

                        return View("EmpDetails");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Error = "Selected excel file not supported";
                        return View("EmpDetails");
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string message = string.Format("<b>Message:</b> {0}<br /><br />", "You do not have access to this view");
                message += string.Format("<b>StackTrace:</b> {0}<br /><br />", ex.StackTrace.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
                message += string.Format("<b>Source:</b> {0}<br /><br />", ex.Source.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
                message += string.Format("<b>TargetSite:</b> {0}", ex.TargetSite.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty));
                ModelState.AddModelError("Id", message);
                
            }
          
            return View("EmpDetails");
        }
```

This is working properly when I debug the code and run from it using VS. When I applied to the live version, can't upload the excel file there is an exception triggering  `You do not have access to this view`

Want to know how to prevent this or how to do same using `stream` ?

Comment: Post the full exception, not just the message you declared in the catch

Comment: Also.. just out of curiosity - you have Excel (Office) installed on the server?

Comment: @riffnl Hi! No, the server is not installed.

Comment: @riffnl I have tried installing the MS Office package to the server. But it still issues is triggering.

Comment: And how did you envision using the Excel interop when there is no Office to interop with? That's your main problem: you should look for an OpenXml package to substitute your Excel interop with like OpenXml,. EPPlus or others

Comment: @riffnl is there any example can you find like this scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249588/discussion-between-riffnl-and-dev-beginner).